# JavaFX8 Build windows executable from macosx

Tags: maven, deployment, javafx, java-8, javafx-8

I am using macosx, maven and javafx 8. 
I have succesfully configure the [maven javafx plugin](http://zenjava.com/javafx/maven/) to generate a dmg. Now i want to to generate a windows executable.

The [packaging tool](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/self-contained-packaging.htm#A1324980) seems to only be able to do it from window, even if this documentation if for javafx 2.2. 
I wouldn't like to install a windows VM on my mac.

I have found [launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) but the [maven plugin](https://github.com/lukaszlenart/launch4j-maven-plugin) looks outdated.

My questions are:

- Will the javafx packaging tool be updated (8u20, 8u40) to support this feature  ?
- Are there free solutions ?

Comment: `Launch4j` is definitely not outdated !

Comment: The last commit on `launch4j-maven-plugin` was 2 years ago.

Comment: Well I am not aware of the `plugin`, but you can definitely create an executable jar and then use [Launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) to make an executable. Though, I am not sure, whether it is crossplatform or not i.e. whether `exe` can be created on Mac, but its worth a try . The last update can be seen [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/launch4j/files/launch4j-3/3.4/)

Comment: Currently this is not indended, but there exists an JIRA-bug-entry for generating native launchers/bundles on other operation systems: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8091902 ... but as this is proprietary on each system (like calling some tools which are not present on other systems).